# How to share enums with client and server in java

Tags: java, enums, client-server, shared-libraries

I am trying to figure out the best practice of sharing enums with the server and client that will always hold the exact same data. I know if I simply copy and paste the code into the client that the server has then it will not work, but how would I go about sharing this "library" of objects between the two?

For example:

```
public enum Misc
{
    BAG     ("Bag", 10, 1),
    MAP     ("Map", 10, 1),
    SCROLL  ("Sroll", 10, 1),
    WAND    ("Wand", 10, 1),
    POTION  ("Potion", 10, 1);

    private String name;
    private int value;
    private double weight;

    Misc(String name, int value, double weight)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public String getName() { return this.name; }
    public int value() { return this.value; }
    public double weight() { return this.weight; }
}
```

I will be sending these enums over the network, such as writing Misc.BAG.toString() over the network from server to client. On the Client I will need to convert the received string back to Misc.BAG that will be on the client. Will simply having a Items.jar as a library  with the same enums and use Misc.ValueOf() to convert it back to the enum work or no? I am getting controversial answers when I googled with some saying yes and no.

If I cannot do the former, how would I go about making simple references to the enums between client and server?

Comment: I don't know about java, but in C# you would usually put these into a common assembly (dll), which is then referenced from both client and server applications.

Comment: I looked into that route as well. Someone had a similar question if that would work and the response was basically "You cannot do this because the life of the enum on the JVM is only once and will not maintain a consistent value for lookups" However I do not know if that is correct. I always thought the whole point of enums was basically a constant with a specific set of values.

Comment: I don't think this qualifies as a valid question...

Comment: Are you trying to share the code? (package into a 'shared.jar' perhaps) or are you trying to send the value of a enum variable across a client/server connection? (serialisation/deserialisation)

Comment: Logically, it would be best to share the code, as values will not change, but the possibility of adding more in updates exists. There's no need to send this data across the network unless I actually *have* to in order to create them. From what I gathered from googling I couldn't do that, but judging by the comments and negative attitude so far I must have found answers from people who did not know what they were talking about.

Comment: If the two enums have the same serialversionUID and contain the same elements, I think (de)serialization should work. If it doesn't, it should be easy to override it by passing a enumName string and performing the lookup receiver-side.

Comment: @Patrick have a look at [1.12 Serialization of Enum Constants](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#enum), it may help your understanding of the single instance of enum issue of which you may have heard

Comment: @Patrick again, knowing nothing about java, I can't give you an answer to this, but I can give you one hint about how it works in the .Net world: WCF is able to deserialize types that are known to both sides automatically, therefore when a Web service method has a parameter that is shared, it uses the type information from the known assembly (dll) in both sides to serialize / deserialize the data.

Comment: @Patrick the link you posted inside your question says the exact opposite than you. It basically states that enum (de)serialization works, by means of the Java standard serialization API. So I think you should remake your question, focusing more on what you're actually trying to do (on a code level) than on the abstract problem.

Comment: @Guilio I know. That was the post I found that gave me the idea that it was the solution, and not the controversial article. I'd have to dig through my history that stated it would not work.
Updated question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong about having that class in both applications? Simply create a package, which will be included in both client and server.

Comment: See my comment to HighCore, right before yours for reasoning/research I found.

Comment: Ill try to be as clear as possible: How would I share a set of enums between a client and server that will retain exact values when references are being transmitted over the net. I will be sending the UID of the enums over the network and these values much match on the client and server.

Comment: @Patrick You mean enum **objects** or enum **classes** (code)?

Comment: Objects, but I updated my question with exact process I will be trying to implement...